# How to unique multiple column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, constraints, primary-key

I am working with SQL Server 2012 and I have one table that has 3 constraint primary key. I just want table structure like that =>

Combination of this 3 column must be unique

```
ColumnA  ColumnB ColumnC
1         2        3
1         2        4
```

But when I test this table, This table can accept duplicate data like that=>

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
1        2        3
1        2        3
```

[image]

Why can I add duplicate value like that even constraint primary key? or Am I misunderstanding about constraint primary?

Comment: Looks like there is another column in the primary key.

Comment: Follow the duplicate link for an answer.  I couldn't say it any better myself.

Comment: @cha, There is no primary key anymore.

Comment: Can you click on the Indexes button in your SSMS and double-check?

Comment: Yep, I already check this. There is no other primary key.

Comment: Can you share the complete table script? It shouldn't allow duplicate values unless strings are being prefixed with white spaces.